# Need each row total value and that should be display at end of row

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I want to display each row's total value at the end of each row...all the records are being fetched from a database but how to count each row's total value and how to display it at the end of every row?  Please help.

```html
<table class="rwd-table ui form" id="myTable">
      
 
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="50%">DATE</th>
    <th>TARGET DAILY CONSUMPTION MMBTU</th>
    <th>CONSUMPTION FROM 00H TO 12H IN MMSCF</th>
    <th>CONSUMPTION FROM 12H TO 24H IN MMSCF</th> 
    <th>CONSUMPTION PER RAK GAS IN MMBTU</th>
    <th>REASON OF VARIATION OF CONSUMPTION BETWEEN ACTUAL & TARGET</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($view as $report) {?>
    <tr style="color: #000000;">
    <td><?php echo $report['date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $report['Target Daily Consumption in MMBTU'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $report['Consumption From 00h to 12h in MMSCF'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $report['Consumption From 12h to 24h in MMSCF'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $report['Consumption As Per RAK Gas in MMBTU'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $report['Reason of Variation of Consumption Between ACTUAL & TARGET'];?></td> 
  </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the actual result is comming inside `<td>`, which needs to be Add

Comment: what is total value here and how to get it?

Comment: You have all the options open, Do it using `PHP` or use `JavaScript` after `DOMConentLoaded`

Comment: Are you using `Jquery` or `Javascript`?

Comment: the result in table is numeric value...i.e...6

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a variable before the loop like:

```
$tot = 0;
```

Then after the sum_total calc you add:

```
$tot += $sum_total;
```

I also would do a little change to sum_total (if you work with integers):

```
$sum_total = intval( $row['stock_count'] ) * intval( $row['stock_price'] );
```

or (if you work with floats):

```
$sum_total = floatval( $row['stock_count'] ) * floatval( $row['stock_price'] );
```

And with:

```
echo number_format( $sum_total, 2 );
```

You can print the float with 2 decimals.